# Bulk update with datanucleus errors out

Tags: datanucleus, jdoql

I'm trying to use the JDOQL bulk update in datanucleus, but I get the following exception,

12/08/13 13:06:56 INFO DataNucleus.Persistence: Property datanucleus.cache.level2 unknown - will be ignored
12/08/13 13:06:56 INFO DataNucleus.Persistence: ================= Persistence Configuration ===============
12/08/13 13:06:56 INFO DataNucleus.Persistence: DataNucleus Persistence Factory - Vendor: "DataNucleus"  Version: "2.2.5"
12/08/13 13:06:56 INFO DataNucleus.Persistence: DataNucleus Persistence Factory initialised for datastore URL="jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true" driver="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" userName="APP"
12/08/13 13:06:56 INFO DataNucleus.Persistence: ===========================================================
12/08/13 13:06:57 INFO Datastore.Schema: Initialising Catalog "", Schema "APP" using "None" auto-start option
12/08/13 13:06:57 INFO Datastore.Schema: Catalog "", Schema "APP" initialised - managing 0 classes
12/08/13 13:06:57 INFO DataNucleus.MetaData: Registering listener for metadata initialisation

Query to be executed: UPDATE myDomain.MTable t SET t.tableName = 'tmp3' WHERE t.tableName == 'tmp'
12/08/13 13:06:57 INFO DataNucleus.JDO: Exception thrown
JPQL UPDATE query has no update clause! Query should be like "UPDATE Entity e SET e.param = new_value WHERE [where-clause]"
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: JPQL UPDATE query has no update clause! Query should be like "UPDATE Entity e SET e.param = new_value WHERE [where-clause]"
    at org.datanucleus.query.JDOQLSingleStringParser$Compiler.compileUpdate(JDOQLSingleStringParser.java:236)
    at org.datanucleus.query.JDOQLSingleStringParser$Compiler.compileSelect(JDOQLSingleStringParser.java:160)
    at org.datanucleus.query.JDOQLSingleStringParser$Compiler.compile(JDOQLSingleStringParser.java:125)
    at org.datanucleus.query.JDOQLSingleStringParser$Compiler.access$000(JDOQLSingleStringParser.java:114)
    at org.datanucleus.query.JDOQLSingleStringParser.parse(JDOQLSingleStringParser.java:106)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.AbstractJDOQLQuery.(AbstractJDOQLQuery.java:108)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.JDOQLQuery.(JDOQLQuery.java:119)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:597)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:324)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.QueryManager.newQuery(QueryManager.java:264)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.newQuery(JDOPersistenceManager.java:1272)

I'm using DN-core-2.2.4, DN-RDBMS-2.2.4, DN-Enhancer-2.1.3 and DN-ConnectionPool-2.0.3.

The code snippet that I fires the update is as follows,

```
openTransaction();
Query q = pm.newQuery("javax.jdo.query.JDOQL", query);
q.compile();
Collection<?> result = (Collection<?>) q.execute();
committed = commitTransaction();
```

Any pointers on what I'm doing wrong.

My query is of the form "UPDATE myDomain.A t SET t.tableName = 'tmp3' WHERE t.tableName == 'tmp'"

Comment: I think your version of DataNucleus is very old, and likely not supported now